# get full string before and after a specific pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking to grab noise text that has a specific pattern in it:

```
text = "this is some text lskdfmd&@kjansdl and some more text sldkf&@lsakjd and some other stuff"
```

I want to be able to remove everything in this sentence where after a space, and before a space contains &@.

```
result = "this is some text and some more text and some other stuff"
```

been trying:

```
re.compile(r'([\s]&@.*?([\s])).sub(" ", text)
```

I can't seem to get the first part though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex to capture that noise string,

```
\s+\S*&@\S*\s+
```

and replace it with a single space.

Here, `\s+` matches any whitespace(s) then `\S*` matches zero or more non-whitespace characters while sandwiching `&@` within it and again `\S*` matches zero or more whitespace(s) and finally followed by `\s+` one or more whitespace which gets removed by a space, giving you your intended string.

Also, if this noise string can be either at the very start or very end of string, feel free to change `\s+` to `\s*`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Vmu84/1)**

Python code,

```
import re

s = 'this is some text lskdfmd&@kjansdl and some more text sldkf&@lsakjd and some other stuff'
print(re.sub(r'\s+\S*&@\S*\s+', ' ', s))
```

Prints,

```
this is some text and some more text and some other stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
import re
result = re.findall(r"[a-zA-z]+\&\@[a-zA-z]+", text) 
print(result)
['lskdfmd&@kjansdl', 'sldkf&@lsakjd']
```

now remove the `result` list from the list of all words.

**Edit1** Suggest by @Jan

```
re.sub(r"[a-zA-z]+\&\@[a-zA-z]+", '', text)
output: 'this is some text  and some more text  and some other stuff'
```

**Edit2** Suggested by @Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi

```
re.sub(r" [a-zA-z]+\&\@[a-zA-z]+ ", " ", text)
output:'this is some text and some more text and some other stuff'
```

Comment: Yes, no issue with this.

Comment: @Jan, use this way:  `re.sub(r"[a-zA-z]+\&\@[a-zA-z]+", '', text)
Output: 'this is some text  and some more text  and some other stuff'`

Comment: This substitution leaves two spaces instead of one that is desired. Also you don't need to uselessly escape `&` and `@`

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
\S+&@\S+\s*
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jCDdE7/1/).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re
text = "this is some text lskdfmd&@kjansdl and some more text sldkf&@lsakjd and some other stuff"
rx = re.compile(r'\S+&@\S+\s*')
text = rx.sub('', text)
print(text)
```

Which yields

```
this is some text and some more text and some other stuff
```